# Blackberry Emulator canot be run on VmPlayer

Tags: blackberry-simulator, vmware-player

when i start the blackberry simulator(10.2) ON VMWAREPLAYER(linux 10.04), on the screen it is showing the following error

"[Error SUD : Cannot verify package id is invalid, Missing]"

[image]

This error is due to the ram shortage only??Because Simulator need minimum 4 GB ram requirement.MY system contain only 2 GB RAM.

Alternative things are also welcome